# im facing type errorr object of type cx_oracle has no len()

Tags: python, cx-oracle

[![enter image description here][1]][1]hi im facing type error cx+_orcle has no len() can you please help

````
query1="SELECT B.RMT_SITE_NM, A.CO_APPL_PRFL_ID, A.PRFL_ID FROM MIGRATION_TRACKING A, T_SFT_INIT_PRTCL B WHERE A.PRFL_ID=B.INIT_PRTCL_ID AND A.STATUS='Scheduled' AND A.PHASE='Phase 1' AND A.WAVE='Wave 1'"
cursor = connection()
    ans = cursor.execute(query1)
    if ans:
        for rows in range(len(ans)):
            name = str(ans[rows][0])
            co_id_table = cursor.execute(query2,(name))
            if co_id_table:
                co_id = co_id_table[0][17]
                data = cursor.execute(query3,(co_id))
                data = data[0]
                rndm_id = generate_id() ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsnMs.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bttB1.jpg
````

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: hi i have add pic you can check now

Comment: Images are hard to work with.  They can't be searched or cut-n-pasted, and they're hard to read for people with low vision.  You'll probably get more help if you post as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

This is the incorrect way of iterating over rows. You should instead do this:

```py
for row in cursor.execute(query1):
    name = str(row[0])
    ...
```

If you prefer to get all of the rows up front (since you are going to use the same cursor to execute other queries), then you can do this:

```py
cursor.execute(query1)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

The value returned from cursor.execute() when the statement executed is a query is simply the cursor itself. Since the cursor implements the iteration protocol, you can also do this:

```py
cursor.execute(query1)
rows = list(cursor)
```